# Write new line adding +1 to base value until total value = 10?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm currently starting to learn Javascript and would be grateful for some help with the following issue:

I'm trying to make a loop that writes a new line with a base value that adds by 1 with each line until the value is equal to 10. Basically, it's supposed to look like this:

Answer: 1
Answer: 2
Answer: 3

... and so on, until it reaches 10. There' the loop should end.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop like so:

```
for(var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) //start x as equal to one, run the code, and repeat until x is 10
    console.log("Answer: " + x);//Print x
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution. Do not use in anything serious:

```
for (x=1;x<11;x++)
{
    document.write("Answer: "+x+"<br />");
}
```

More versatile solution with DOM ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5mRv/1/)):

```
<p id="numbers">
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
for (x=1;x<11;x++)
{
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML+="Answer: "+x+"<br />"
}
</script>
```